# Solution to day_num problem in "think python 3" book

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is exercise in section 4.17 of the book "How to Think Like a Computer
Scientist: Learning with Python 3" 3rd edition

"Write a function day_name that converts an integer number 0 to 6 into the name of a day. Assume day 0 is “Sunday”. Once again, return None if the arguments to the function are not valid."

I have written the following code which solves the problem for most part, except i am unable to understand how to return "None" for invalid argument. Please assist...

```
def day_name(x):
    days=["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    return days[x]

print(day_name(5))
```

if i `print(day_name(7))`, it returns python error instead of "None"

Comment: How about an if statement?

Comment: You can just intercept the error and return None

Answer (score 3):

Add validation to your function. You can do this explicitly:

```
if x in range(7):
    return days[x]
else:
    return None
```

That is called *look before you leap*: you check that `days[x]` exists before you try to select it.

Or you can let the selection fail and trap the error:

```
try:
    return days[x]
except IndexError:
    return None
```

Comment: +1 correct, I will just add the second paradigm is called "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the list data structure. It works based on the indexes.

```
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    0         1          2          3            4          5           6
```

When we access `print(day_name(7))` then we are trying to access index `7` which is not available. so, it's throwing the error.

Better Approach is

```
def day_name(x):
    days = {
        0: 'Sunday',
        1: 'Monday',
        2: 'Tuesday',
        3: 'Wednesday',
        4: 'Thursday',
        5: 'Friday',
        6: 'Saturday'
     }

    return dic.get(x)

print(day_name(7))
```

Dictionary works faster because it uses hashing technique.

## Speed testing list index vs dict key

```
from time import time
t = time()
lst = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
try:
    print(lst[7])
except IndexError:
    pass

print(time() - t)

t = time()
days = {
    0: 'Sunday',
    1: 'Monday',
    2: 'Tuesday',
    3: 'Wednesday',
    4: 'Thursday',
    5: 'Friday',
    6: 'Saturday'
}
print(days.get(7))

print(time() - t)
```

## Output

```
None
3.09944152832e-05
None
1.09672546387e-05
```

For more derails checkout https://learnbatta.com/course/python/python-working-with-lists/

Comment: Thanks, so whats the better way to solve the exercise problem?

Comment: @njathan use `try-except`

Comment: @njathan we only have `7` days, it means `0 to 6` indexes. So, we should not access the index `7`.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar `try-exept` works but that's not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I don't see any problem with it or `dict` is much better option here. See my answer below.

Comment: I would saw the more pythonic way is `try-except` but the better way should be using dict. If you are saying the dict method is faster please provide tryit stats.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth checkout the stats with above code using `time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def day_name(x):
    days=["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    try:
        return days[x]
    except:
        return None
```

You can use a for loop but this is the better way to go. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

As @Derte said,it is also a good practise to catch only the specific exception instead of blanket except statement like:

```
def day_name(x):
    days=["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    try:
        return days[x]
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

Here's a time testing using timeit library:

```
import timeit
def day_name_eafp(x):
    days=["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    try:
        return days[x]
    except IndexError as e:
        return None

def day_name_dict(x):
    days = {
        0: 'Sunday',
        1: 'Monday',
        2: 'Tuesday',
        3: 'Wednesday',
        4: 'Thursday',
        5: 'Friday',
        6: 'Saturday'
     }

    return days.get(x)


def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

x=7
wrapped_eafp = wrapper(day_name_eafp, x)
wrapped_dict = wrapper(day_name_dict, x)

timeit.timeit(wrapped_eafp, number=100000)
>>0.05935070099803852
timeit.timeit(wrapped_dict, number=100000)
>>0.06682577800165745
```

This means the speed is comparable. So of-course you should use a more pythonic way.

Comment: specify the exception type as `except IndexError`, avoid "catch all" excepts in general (for example if user does a keyboard interrupt (CTRL+C) at the right moment the program would not be stopped by it)

Answer (score 0):

The function/method 'day_name' holds a [dict](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) that points from day index to day name.A python dict comes with a function named 'get' which you can read about here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm . It is the 'get' function that takes care of the cases where there is no match between the day_index and the day name.

```
def day_name(day_index):
    days = {0: "Sunday", 1: "Monday", 2: "Tuesday", 3: "Wednesday", 4: "Thursday", 5: "Friday", 6: "Saturday"}
    return days.get(day_index, None)


print(day_name(4))  # Thursday
print(day_name(44))  # None
```

Comment: Commentary was added